# Datatable TableTools not displaying

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

i'm using old datatables... http://legacy.datatables.net/

this is my code...

```
    $('#example').dataTable({
            "sAjaxSource": base_url+"home/getAllData",
            fnServerData: function ( sSource, aoData, fnCallback, oSettings )
            {
                oSettings.jqXHR = $.ajax({
                    "dataType": 'json',
                    "method": 'GET',
                    "url": sSource,
                    "data": aoData,
                    "success": fnCallback
                });
            },
            "sDom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
            "oTableTools": {
                "aButtons": [
                    "copy",
                    "print",
                    {
                        "sExtends":    "collection",
                        "sButtonText": "Save",
                        "aButtons":    [ "csv", "xls", "pdf" ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        });
    });
```

no error is display, but it doesnt display any button also, please let me know if im missing anything...

Comment: syntax seemed okay... have you added the TableTools plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to add swfpath.. and make sure to set the correct path.

```
"sSwfPath": "<c:url value="../../swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"/>"
```

For new datatables, check below:

"This extension has now been retired and has been replaced by the Buttons and Select extensions. The documentation is retained for legacy reference only. New projects should use Buttons and Select in preference to TableTools."

http://datatables.net/extensions/tabletools/